# Xcode 8 Jenkins JUnit error: test report no report files found

Tags: java, xcode, unit-testing, jenkins, junit

I'm new to Jenkins and am trying to setup CI for my iOS app. I've created a unit test target in the project and have configured Jenkins to properly build and run my unit tests, but the build fails when trying to actually output the rest results xml file and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I borrowed a lot of ideas presented from these sources:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/22816/beginning-automated-testing-with-xcode-part-22
http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/04/02/advanced-jenkins-for-ios-and-mac/

My actual console log after a build looks like this:

```
=== BUILD TARGET run_to_it OF PROJECT run_to_it WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

=== BUILD TARGET run_to_itTests OF PROJECT run_to_it WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

My build step execute shell looks like this :

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

security unlock-keychain -p ${KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD} ${KEYCHAIN_PATH}
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k ${KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD} ${KEYCHAIN_PATH}
xcrun xcodebuild clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE=${PROVISIONING_PROFILE} OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain ${KEYCHAIN_PATH}"


xcodebuild -target run_to_itTests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=NO WANT_IOS_SIM=YES OBJROOT="${WORKSPACE}"/tmp/objs build | /usr/local/bin/ocunit2junit
```

My post build step for where the test reports are to be placed looks like this: 
[image]

I've ensured I've installed the necessary plugins as well as installing the `ocunit2junit` gem in the `/usr/local/bin` directory as well as having installed the `JUnit` plugin in Jenkins.

[image][image]

I'm not 100% sure if any xml file is being generated at all as I've looked through every folder in the Jenkins workspace and see no such xml file anywhere. I'm not sure if I need to explicitly specify this file to be created in any of the build steps or if it is handled by default. I've looked far and wide on the internet and I've not been able to conclusively figure out the problem.

For context: My Jenkins server is running on my Mac at the moment. I have a Jenkins user with a workspace on my local machine. I'm also running `macOS Sierra` and I'm not sure if there could be any permissions issues with the test-reports folder. I see that the folder is being created but no xml file is ever placed inside of it.

If I remove the `Publish JUnit test report result` then my project will build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Value on Test report XMLs field (Publish JUnit test result report option) seems to be correct. If you don't have any xml file inside this directory after your build, the problem is inside your test (and generation of xml junit result file), not in Publish JUnit test result report configuration.

Can you be sure that your unit test generate result inside xml file, with Junit format?

Comment: Yeah I suspect that to be the problem too, there is no such xml file anywhere that I can find. I've combed through the workspace of the project in the jenkins directory and have found no resulting xml files. Can you elaborate further on what you mean by the problems is inside the test?

Comment: If you want to publish Junit test result report your unit test have to generate result inside xml file with junit format. Is it the case? How do you made your unit test ? What is the output of your unit test?

Comment: My unit test is one separate test target that runs one unit test in the code. I have nothing else configured beyond that.

Comment: Ok, with "publish Junit test result report" plugin, Jenkins will display your test result. But you have to provide these test result. This plugin will not generate the test result in Junit format. It will only display it. Inside your unit test, you have to make something (a script, or other) to output test result in JUnit format (for example, Junit format can be found here : http://help.catchsoftware.com/display/ET/JUnit+Format)

Comment: I was under the assumption that  `| /usr/local/bin/ocunit2junit` pipes the xcode test output into a junit test result format. Is that not the case? In both of the examples I cited, this was the step they added to capture the test result output.

Comment: Ok that's right. I only know about using junit file into Jenkins build. So I didn't know ocunit2junit, but it seems to be the right tool... Do you try your command without pipe to ocunit2junit, to see if output of xcodebuild is good ?

Comment: Yes without piping and without specifying a test-reports folder the build will succeed.

Comment: Ok I'm very sorry but I really don't know about xcode and tool with it... I can't help you more, I'm afraid...